# Outgoing UDP packets don't reach the host from VM after certain time

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, vpn, udp

I am trying to connect to my WireGuard VPN server that is inside a VirtualBox VM. I normally can connect without any problem. But when there isn't any connectivity for a certain time, I can't connect to the VPN. Packets reach out and guest responds, but response packets don't reach out to host.

WG server was created by PiVPN. 51820 port is forwarded for UDP from VirtualBox, VM network adapter is NAT. The same problem doesn't exist in SSH (TCP).

### Current Behavior

Guest:

```
user@host:~$ sudo tcpdump -n -i enp0s3 udp port 51820
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on enp0s3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
09:49:53.291627 IP 10.0.2.2.31083 > 10.0.2.15.51820: UDP, length 148
09:49:53.292606 IP 10.0.2.15.51820 > 10.0.2.2.31083: UDP, length 92
09:49:58.328855 IP 10.0.2.2.31083 > 10.0.2.15.51820: UDP, length 148
09:49:58.329802 IP 10.0.2.15.51820 > 10.0.2.2.31083: UDP, length 92
09:50:03.330680 IP 10.0.2.2.31083 > 10.0.2.15.51820: UDP, length 148
09:50:03.331727 IP 10.0.2.15.51820 > 10.0.2.2.31083: UDP, length 92
```

Host (IP addresses were redacted for privacy):

```
user@host:~$ sudo tcpdump -n -i enp2s0 udp port 51820
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on enp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
09:49:53.299950 IP REDACTED.160.31083 > 192.168.1.2.51820: UDP, length 148
09:49:58.337289 IP REDACTED.160.31083 > 192.168.1.2.51820: UDP, length 148
09:50:03.339227 IP REDACTED.160.31083 > 192.168.1.2.51820: UDP, length 148
```

The packets guest send don't reach out to host. The problem persists whether the VPN client is on Linux or Android, or from WAN or LAN.

But when I shutdown and start the VM (Restarting with `reboot` or from VirtualBox doesn't solve), the problem is solved until certain time.

### Expected Behavior

Example after a fresh start:

Guest:

```
user@host:~$ sudo tcpdump -n -i enp0s3 udp port 51820
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on enp0s3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
10:19:34.839506 IP 10.0.2.15.51820 > 10.0.2.2.31630: UDP, length 148
10:19:36.907337 IP 10.0.2.15.51820 > 10.0.2.2.31630: UDP, length 96
10:19:39.959455 IP 10.0.2.15.51820 > 10.0.2.2.31630: UDP, length 148
10:19:40.737806 IP 10.0.2.15.51820 > 10.0.2.2.31630: UDP, length 96
10:19:42.153683 IP 10.0.2.2.31372 > 10.0.2.15.51820: UDP, length 148
10:19:42.154626 IP 10.0.2.15.51820 > 10.0.2.2.31372: UDP, length 92
10:19:42.188919 IP 10.0.2.2.31372 > 10.0.2.15.51820: UDP, length 96
10:19:42.233622 IP 10.0.2.15.51820 > 10.0.2.2.31372: UDP, length 160
```

Host:

```
user@host:~$ sudo tcpdump -n -i enp2s0 udp port 51820
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on enp2s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
10:19:35.688786 IP 192.168.1.2.51820 > REDACTED.160.31630: UDP, length 148
10:19:37.756607 IP 192.168.1.2.51820 > REDACTED.160.31630: UDP, length 96
10:19:40.808901 IP 192.168.1.2.51820 > REDACTED.160.31630: UDP, length 148
10:19:41.587208 IP 192.168.1.2.51820 > REDACTED.160.31630: UDP, length 96
10:19:43.002201 IP REDACTED.160.31372 > 192.168.1.2.51820: UDP, length 148
10:19:43.004069 IP 192.168.1.2.51820 > REDACTED.160.31372: UDP, length 92
10:19:43.037507 IP REDACTED.160.31372 > 192.168.1.2.51820: UDP, length 96
10:19:43.083059 IP 192.168.1.2.51820 > REDACTED.160.31372: UDP, length 160
```

- VirtualBox Version: 7.0.8 r156879
- Guest OS: Debian 11.7 (No firewall installed)
- Host OS: Linux Mint 21.1 (UFW ON/OFF doesn't change)
- All up to date

I like the convenience of NAT port forwarding. Is there a way to solve this problem permanently without using Bridged Adapter or any other network adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>Setting `pivpnPERSISTENTKEEPALIVE=25` in `/etc/pivpn/wireguard/setupVars.conf` and creating the client configs again like described [here](https://docs.pivpn.io/wireguard/#keep-wireguard-connected-connection-issues-persistentkeepalive) seems to solve the problem.</s>

**EDIT:** The issue is not same but I couldn't establish a WG tunnel with a Fedora guest with pure WG, without PiVPN. WG was working normally with "Bridged Adapter" though, unlike NAT + port forwarding. But it would get a separate 192.168.1.x address from the router and bypasses the host's firewall, both are undesirable. Then I realized something, I was using 10.0.2.0/24 subnet for WG. Do you know who is also using the same subnet range? VirtualBox does, at least in *"NAT"* adapter:

```
[root@fedora user]# ip address

...

2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:92:cc:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s3
```

I changed WG's IP addresses to ones in 10.5.5.0/24 (or any other private IP) and boom, it worked. It was *that* simple.